# Can't use await for a dynamic import statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, import, module

I'm currently writing a dynamic command handler for a console bot.
I am using Node and TypeScript.

My function to load my commands dynamically from the command directory looks like this:

```js
export async function loadCommands(): Promise<void> {
    // read all the files in the commands directory
    const commandFiles = await loadCommandFiles(); // this works fine

    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const { command } = await import(`#commands/${file}`);
        console.log(command);
    }
}
```

What's really weird about this is that as soon as I use `await` in front of the `import` statement, the whole application will just exit without any error even when catching it.
The path is right, the command files also have no issues.

But when I use a the usual promise handling like this:

```js
    import(`#commands/${file}`).then(({ command }) => {
        console.log(command);
    });
```

I have no issues.

The downside of this way is that I can't wait for it and my file which calls this `loadCommands()` function will just continue to run although the commands are not done yet.

Of course, I also tried returning a `Promise` like this:

```js
    // read all the files in the commands directory
    const commandFiles = await loadCommandFiles();

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        import(`#commands/examplefile.js`).then(({ command }) => {
            resolve(command);
        });
    })
```

But although using the promise resolving which worked previously, this will just exit the application again.
Maybe the errors from dynamic imports are not properly thrown but that would not explain why simple resolving is working but `await` does not.

I am kind of clueless right now.

Node: v16.2.0
TypeScript: v4.3.5

I am using `ES2021` as target and `ESNext` as module in order to use top level await.
My package.json also includes the `"type": "modules"` field so using `require` instead of `import` is not a thing I can do.

Comment: So if you surround the `await import(...);` with a try/catch does the catch get called and if so what is the exception?

Comment: If I surround it with a try/catch, the catch block isn't called so there is no exception at all. I also tried debugging it but as soon as it hits the `import` part, the whole process just stops without any error or exception.

Comment: This is really a Javascript question, as dynamic imports are introduced by JS, not Typescript. You can confirm this, and that it is not a TS configuration issue, by looking at the generated JS.  You will probably find your answer searching the web or SO for "await dynamic import". For example: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237824/using-async-await-with-dynamic-import-for-es6-modules